# Async functions blocks the Event Loop - not rendering pages when app.get method is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have crontab that is being executed every hour and a half and this calls to an async function that takes about two minutes to be executed. There is a high probability that app.get method can be called to render a webpage but since the async function is still running, then the page is not being render. Why is this happenning? A simple example

```
var cron = require('node-cron');
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

cron.schedule('30 */1 * * *', () => {
    asyncFunction(url);
});

function asyncFunction(url){
// Do some long task!
}

app.get("/", function( req, res ){ 

// It doesn't render while the contrab executes an async
// function. It seems to be blocking the event loop...

res.render('webpageTemplate',{data: data});

});


let port = process.env.PORT;
if( port == null || port == ""){
  port=3000;
} 

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("server started at port "+port);
});
```

Comment: how can you claim that? since async means it will run asynchronously i.e. not blocking, means it shouldn't bother your GET route

Comment: So, node.js runs your Javascript in a single thread (except for WorkerThreads) so if the interpreter is busy running your function, then it can't do anything else.  For further help, you will have to show us the actual code in `asyncFunction()` so we can see how much it blocks or doesn't.

Comment: I think you should read about micro-tasks over here. https://dev.to/sagarrth/an-overview-of-event-loop-tasks-and-microtasks-1i31  

Quoting "Microtasks are kind of blocking in nature. Unlike macrotasks, the main thread will be blocked until microtask queue is empty".